# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference (VB.net 2010)

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

[image]

Hi guys! i need your help about my program problem, Its about creating events.
It shows "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". I don't have any idea how to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: The code is using `SomeClass.SomeInstanceMember` and it should be `anInstanceOfSomeClass.SomeInstanceMember`: that is what the error is saying. Read through the related questions as there is nothing 'new' here.

Comment: Questions that post screenshots of code rather than the code itself tend to get down voted here.

Answer (score 0):

It means you did not create an instance of an object and are trying to call it's methods directly on a non-shared member.

Example:

```
Public Class Foo
  Public Sub Bar(foobar As String)
    'some stuff
  End Sub
End Class
```

You are doing similar to this:

```
Foo.Bar("foobar")
```

When you need to do this:

```
Dim _foo As New Foo
_foo.Bar("some foobar")
```

Otherwise you could do this:

```
Public Class Foo
  Public Shared Sub Bar(foobar As String)
    'some stuff
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then you can do:

```
Foo.Bar("foobar")
```